# Why isn't my jquery switch statement working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I am trying a jquery (javascript) switch statement with some simple operators but it isn't working as expecting

```
console.log('test '+getShippingCost(8));
function getShippingCost(shop_qty) {
                shipping_costs = 0;
                dest = $("input[name='dest']").val();
                console.log(dest);
                if (dest === 'DOMESTIC') {

                    switch (shop_qty) {
                        case (shop_qty > 4):
                             shipping_costs = 3.5;
                            break;
                        case (shop_qty <= 4):
                             shipping_costs = 2;
                                break;
                        }
                        console.log('domestic shipping '+shipping_costs);
                }
                if (dest === 'INT') {
                            switch (shop_qty) {
                                case (shop_qty > 4):
                                    shipping_costs = 4.5;
                                    break;
                                case (shop_qty <= 4):
                                    shipping_costs = 3;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        return shipping_costs;
                        }//end function
```

see [see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wesweatyoushop/ucouyncy/)

Comment: what is it doing, what are you expecting?

Comment: use an if statement!

Comment: Use an `if` / `else` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use conditions for the cases in a `switch`, you would look for a `true` value among the cases:

```
switch (true) {
  case (shop_qty > 4):
    shipping_costs = 3.5;
    break;
  case (shop_qty <= 4):
    shipping_costs = 2;
    break;
}
```

As the second case is the inverse of the first, you can just use `default` for that:

```
switch (true) {
  case (shop_qty > 4):
    shipping_costs = 3.5;
    break;
  default:
    shipping_costs = 2;
    break;
}
```

Such a construct fits better when you have several conditions. You should consider if an `if` statement would be a better fit in this case:

```
if (shop_qty > 4) {
    shipping_costs = 3.5;
} else {
    shipping_costs = 2;
}
```

As both cases assign a value to the same variable, you can also write it using the conditional operator:

```
shipping_costs = shop_qty > 4 ? 3.5 : 2;
```

Comment: Are you sure about `switch (true)`?

Comment: A quick test show me you are correct, i wasn't really expecting it. Thx for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Cases in `switch` statements evaluate values, not boolean expressions: [See Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

You can put the logic suggested by your attempted use of the `switch` statement in a ternary expression, e.g.:

```
shipping_costs = (shop_qty > 4) ? 3.5 : 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch doesn't work by evaluating boolean expressions. Switch evaluates an initial expression and then tries to match the cases to that expression using strict equality. So you can't do

```
case(x<4.5):
```

You have to do something like

```
case 4:
```

Use if, else if, else statments instead.